# CloudKit save operation storing Int(0) and String("") as empty [object Object]

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

A few days from now CloudKit started storing integers with value 0 and strings with value "" as literals [object Object].

[image]

Everything works fine behind the scenes, but CloudKit web interface shows [object Object] instead of 0 and "".

Tried to recreate the the record type but no success.

In addition to that, if you try to save an Int(64) as 0(zero) manually using the cloudKit web interface it wont store a 0 value, it will store a NIL. Same for "" strings.

Is anyone else experiencing the same issues?!

Comment: Yes, I am seeing this too!!  Very annoying.

Comment: This string apparently is coming from Javascript.  I found this: The default conversion from an object to string is "[object Object]".  This is yet another example of how unstable and untested cloudKit is, particularly for a product that is over three years old and from Apple!

Comment: Yeah, really annoying... just logged a bug with Apple then. Such a pain to test some stuff as I need to modify variables manually in the database to emulate results... simply can't do it until they fix that.

Comment: Finally, this now appears to be fixed!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a display issue when viewing data in the dashboard. The data stored in CloudKit is ok. The display bug is a known issue and will be fixed soon.

Comment: Not only an issue when viewing data on dashboard. If you, through the web interface, try to save an Int(64) as 0 (zero) it won't save the 0 value, but it will save a NIL value. Same for "" strings. When you think all booleans in cloudKit are Int(64) = 0, making a 0 become a NIL just crashes everything.